Create Jenkins Credential Certificates via API - This page expects a from submission
We are trying to create Jenkins Certificate Credentials over the API in a script which generates a App Registration in Azure and then should put the corresponding certificate into the Jenkins Credential store.
We are on Jenkins version 2.426.2
Does anyone know how the form needs to be submitted in order to create the credential?
Here is our code:
$form = @{
        'id'          = $CredentialId
        'description' = $CredentialDescription
        'file'        = $CertificateFilePath
        'password'    = $CertificatePassword
    }
$userId = $env:JENKINSAPIUSER
$token = $env:JENKINSTOKEN
$pair = "$($userId):$($token)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
$headers = @{
        'Authorization' = "Basic $encodedCreds"
    }
    $jenkinsUri = "$JenkinsUrl/credentials/store/$CredentialStore/domain/_/createCredentials/"
    Invoke-RestMethod -uri $jenkinsUri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Form $form


Which returns:

Text: Error 400 This page expects a form submission
The same behavior happens in Postman:

As you can see it also adds the required headers:

We also tried adding it over the xml api:
$xmlPayload = @"
    <com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.CertificateCredentialsImpl>
        <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
        <id>$CredentialId</id>
        <description>$CredentialDescription</description>
        <file>$([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($CertificateFilePath)))</file>
        <password>$($CertificatePassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText)</password>
    </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.CertificateCredentialsImpl>
"@

    #$response = Invoke-JenkinsWebRequest -Uri $jenkinsUri -Method Post -Form $json
    $response = Invoke-JenkinsWebRequest -Uri "$jenkinsUri/config.xml" -Method Post -Body $xmlPayload -ContentType "application/xml"

which results in an empty credential entry:


Furthermore, we tried to reverse engineer the web ui - which lead to no significant insights. However here is the function we identified for preparing the data for the form:
 
function buildFormTree(form) {
  try {
    // I initially tried to use an associative array with DOM elements as keys
    // but that doesn't seem to work neither on IE nor Firefox.
    // so I switch back to adding a dynamic property on DOM.
    form.formDom = {}; // root object
 
    var doms = []; // DOMs that we added 'formDom' for.
    doms.push(form);
 
    let addProperty = function (parent, name, value) {
      name = shortenName(name);
      if (parent[name] != null) {
        if (parent[name].push == null) {
          // is this array?
          parent[name] = [parent[name]];
        }
        parent[name].push(value);
      } else {
        parent[name] = value;
      }
    };
 
    // find the grouping parent node, which will have @name.
    // then return the corresponding object in the map
    let findParent = function (e) {
      var p = findFormParent(e, form);
      if (p == null) {
        return {};
      }
 
      var m = p.formDom;
      if (m == null) {
        // this is a new grouping node
        doms.push(p);
        p.formDom = m = {};
        addProperty(findParent(p), p.getAttribute("name"), m);
      }
      return m;
    };
 
    var jsonElement = null;
 
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
      var e = form.elements[i];
      if (e.name == "json") {
        jsonElement = e;
        continue;
      }
      if (e.tagName == "FIELDSET") {
        continue;
      }
      if (e.tagName == "SELECT" && e.multiple) {
        var values = [];
        for (var o = 0; o < e.options.length; o++) {
          var opt = e.options.item(o);
          if (opt.selected) {
            values.push(opt.value);
          }
        }
        addProperty(findParent(e), e.name, values);
        continue;
      }
 
      var p;
      var r;
      var type = e.getAttribute("type");
      if (type == null) {
        type = "";
      }
      switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
        case "button":
        case "submit":
          break;
        case "checkbox":
          p = findParent(e);
          var checked = xor(e.checked, e.classList.contains("negative"));
          if (!e.groupingNode) {
            let v = e.getAttribute("json");
            if (v) {
              // if the special attribute is present, we'll either set the value or not. useful for an array of checkboxes
              // we can't use @value because IE6 sets the value to be "on" if it's left unspecified.
              if (checked) {
                addProperty(p, e.name, v);
              }
            } else {
              // otherwise it'll bind to boolean
              addProperty(p, e.name, checked);
            }
          } else {
            if (checked) {
              addProperty(p, e.name, (e.formDom = {}));
            }
          }
          break;
        case "file":
          // to support structured form submission with file uploads,
          // rename form field names to unique ones, and leave this name mapping information
          // in JSON. this behavior is backward incompatible, so only do
          // this when
          p = findParent(e);
          if (e.getAttribute("jsonAware") != null) {
            var on = e.getAttribute("originalName");
            if (on != null) {
              addProperty(p, on, e.name);
            } else {
              var uniqName = "file" + iota++;
              addProperty(p, e.name, uniqName);
              e.setAttribute("originalName", e.name);
              e.name = uniqName;
            }
          }
          // switch to multipart/form-data to support file submission
          // @enctype is the standard, but IE needs @encoding.
          form.enctype = form.encoding = "multipart/form-data";
          crumb.appendToForm(form);
          break;
        case "radio":
          if (!e.checked) {
            break;
          }
          r = 0;
          while (e.name.substring(r, r + 8) == "removeme") {
            r = e.name.indexOf("_", r + 8) + 1;
          }
          p = findParent(e);
          if (e.groupingNode) {
            addProperty(
              p,
              e.name.substring(r),
              (e.formDom = { value: e.value }),
            );
          } else {
            addProperty(p, e.name.substring(r), e.value);
          }
          break;
        case "password":
          p = findParent(e);
          addProperty(p, e.name, e.value);
          // must be kept in sync with RedactSecretJsonForTraceSanitizer.REDACT_KEY
          addProperty(p, "$redact", shortenName(e.name));
          break;
        default:
          p = findParent(e);
          addProperty(p, e.name, e.value);
          if (e.classList.contains("complex-password-field")) {
            addProperty(p, "$redact", shortenName(e.name));
          }
          break;
      }
    }
 
    jsonElement.value = JSON.stringify(form.formDom);
 
    // clean up
    for (i = 0; i < doms.length; i++) {
      doms[i].formDom = null;
    }
 
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e + "\n(form not submitted)");
    return false;
  }
}


Looking at your PowerShell code the problem is with the form data encoding. Jenkins expects application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but when you supply -Form parameter Invoke-RestMethod sends multipart/form-data. Replace -Form with -Body parameter.

That leads to the exact same result, so this answer must be wrong.
